# How to create a variable length array/vector of String ^ in VC++

Tags: arrays, visual-c++

I'm trying to create a vector of System::String ^, I tried using the straight up STL vector, but `vector<String ^>  my_vector`  gives a C4439 error (function needs to have a __clrcall calling convention.

So, I added __clrcall to my function prototype, and it still complained about my declaration of `vector<String ^>`.

I'm also reading through the MSDN pages on the VC++ library, but I haven't found what I need yet, anybody out there know what I need?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to put a managed object (the String) under control of an unmanaged object, but the managed heap can move things around in memory and that's a problem for the vector. Basically, you can't stick managed objects into STL containers, though it may be allowed in managed C++ with pinning (I haven't tried that) and getting the actual char * out of it.

However, .NET provides similar classes such as the `List<T>` generic that will do the same thing for you, but in managed code. If you're on an older version of .NET, look at something like `ArrayList`, `Stack`, or `Queue`.

Comment: An ArrayList was almost exactly what I was hoping for, but I couldn't find it for some reason.  Thanks.

Comment: No prob. If you can use the generic 'List<T>' instead, that's a better option because you'll get type checking that you won't get with an ArrayList.